# How to add separator field to user profile

Tags: users

I'm creating new fields for the user profile.

I have this:

- Company Name
- City
- Logo
- etc

**I need to add a new field or some kind of header/separator with this "CONTACT INFORMATION"**

and then a bunch of other fields

- Name
- Email
- Address

Basically I need to divide the fields by sections, I just need it to be visible, no programming purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:
Add *one* contact field that has cardinality 3 and stores the name, email and address.

Option 2:
Alter the form and put name, email and address in one *fieldset*.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Option 2: How can I add a fieldset?

Comment: As a refence you can use the implementation of contact_form_user_form_alter in the core module contact. There a details element is added. You can add a fieldset the same way.